# Storing a PostgreSQL ARRAY of ENUM values

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table that can have a status:

```
statuses = ['unmoderated', 'nominee', 'finalist', 'winner']
status = db.Enum(
    *statuses, name='enum_nomination_status', metadata=db.metadata)


class Nomination(db.Model):
    status = db.Column(status, default='unmoderated')
```

I would now like to have a table that has a column that can contain multiple statuses:

```
class Judge(db.Model):
    statuses = db.Column(ARRAY(status, dimensions=1))
```

However the above approach leads me to this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "statuses" is of type enum_nomination_status[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: ...4, 'Name', ARRAY['unm...
                  ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

So I tried to create a custom type that did the cast to the enum type:

```
class STATUS_ARRAY(TypeDecorator):
    impl = ARRAY(status, dimensions=1)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return cast(array(value), ARRAY(status, dimensions=1))
```

But this causes a segfault.

I've also tried casting the individual items:

```
class STATUS_ARRAY(TypeDecorator):
    impl = ARRAY(status, dimensions=1)

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return array(cast(s, status) for s in value)
```

But I get:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Cast' [SQL: 'INSERT INTO judge (statuses) VALUES (%(statuses)s)'] [parameters: {'statuses': [<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Cast object at 0x7fc8bb69c710>]}]
```

I admit that I'm mostly trying different combinations of casting things without really knowing what's going on underneath the hood. I tried looking at the underlying ENUM implementation to see if I could get at some kind of native enum type without casting but I couldn't see anything. I'm grasping at straws.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'd suggest you use the [enum recipe](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2011/01/14/the-enum-recipe/), written by the author of `sqlalchemy`.

Comment: I just ran into this as well, and submitted this as [issue 3467](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3467/array-of-enums-does-not-allow-assigning) to SQLAlchemy's issue tracker.

Comment: I'm having this issue too.  I've basically tried everything that you've done too, but no joy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### As of 1.3.17, no workaround is needed anymore

The answer below ended up in the docs as [ARRAY of ENUM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#using-enum-with-array). This docs page now says:

> **Changed in version 1.3.17**: The combination of ENUM and ARRAY is now directly handled by SQLAlchemy’s implementation without any workarounds needed.

### Old answer for historical purposes:

I looked at [Issue 3467](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#using-enum-with-array) posted by Wichert Akkerman, and this work-around was posted.  Credit to Mike Bayer.  Declare the following class in your code (with the necessary imports, of course):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy import cast

class ArrayOfEnum(ARRAY):
    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return cast(bindvalue, self)

    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        super_rp = super(ArrayOfEnum, self).result_processor(dialect, coltype)

        def handle_raw_string(value):
            if value==None:
                return []
            inner = re.match(r"^{(.*)}$", value).group(1)
            return inner.split(",")

        def process(value):
            return super_rp(handle_raw_string(value))
        return process
```

`ArrayOfEnum` is now a special column type that gets used in the model definition.

So instead of

```
class Judge(db.Model):
    statuses = db.Column(ARRAY(status))
```

Now you can do:

```
class Judge(db.Model):
    statuses = db.Column(ArrayOfEnum(status))
```

Now in your code you can assign values to `statuses` with a list and it will do the proper casting upon saving:

```
my_judge_object.status = ['unmoderated', 'nominee']
```

Comment: I've not tested this personally yet but I'd be very surprised if it didn't work :) Cheers!

Comment: I had to add some smalll changes from Mike's post, like adding `if value==None: return []` and may have forgotten an import.  If you find a bug or something missing, feel free to comment and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Instead of defining an array for `my_judge_object.status` am I able to define a class by importing `from enum import Enum` and applying `class EnumName(Enum):` to define `key = 'value'`-pairs of enums, like `alternative ='Alternative'` ?

Comment: And what is the type of import i have to do to use `ArrayOfEnum`