# ProgrammingError: column "product" is of type product[] but expression is of type text[] enum postgres

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, enums

I would like to save array of enums.

I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE public.campaign
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  product product[]
)
```

product is an `enum`.

In Django I defined it like this:

```
PRODUCT = (
    ('car', 'car'),
    ('truck', 'truck')
)
class Campaign(models.Model):
    product = ArrayField(models.CharField(null=True, choices=PRODUCT))
```

However, when I write the following:

```
campaign = Campaign(id=5, product=["car", "truck"])
campaign.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "product" is of type product[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: ..."product" = ARRAY['car...
```

**Note**
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783942/storing-a-postgresql-array-of-enum-values) answer, but I don't use sqlalchemy and would rather not use it if not needed.

**EDITED**
I tried @Roman Konoval suggestion below like this:

```
class PRODUCT(Enum):
    CAR = 'car'
    TRUCK = 'truck'

class Campaign(models.Model):
        product = ArrayField(EnumField(PRODUCT, max_length=10))
```

and with:

```
campaign = Campaign(id=5, product=[CAR, TRUCK])
campaign.save()
```

However, I still get the same error,

I see that django is translating it to list of strings.
if I write the following directly the the psql console:

```
INSERT INTO campaign ("product") VALUES ('{car,truck}'::product[])
```

it works just fine

Comment: How you define product in postgresql - as CREATE TYPE, TABLE?

Comment: I defined it as enu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two fundamental problems here.

### Don't use Enums

If you continue to use enum, your next question here on Stackoverflow will be "how do I add a new entry to an enum?". Django does not support enum type out of the box (thank heavens). So you have to use third party libraries for this. Your mileage will vary with how complete the library is.

> An enum value occupies four bytes on disk. The length of an enum
>   value's textual label is limited by the NAMEDATALEN setting compiled
>   into PostgreSQL; in standard builds this means at most 63 bytes.

If you are thinking that you are saving space on disk by using enum, the above quote from the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-enum.html) shows that it's an illusion.

See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318123/postgresql-enum-what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages) for more on advantages and disadvantages of enum. But generally the disadvantages outweigh the advantages.

### Don't use Arrays

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/arrays.html

If you are going to search for a campaign that deals with Cars or Trucks you are going to have to do a lot of hard work. So will the database.

### The correct design

The correct design is the one suggested in the postgresql arrays documentation page. Create a related table. This is the standard django way as well.

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Product(Models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
```

This makes your code simpler. Doesn't require any extra storage. Doesn't require third party libraries. And best of all the vast api of the [django related models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) becomes available to you.

Comment: I thought that postgres only saves one 1 bit for the value of the enum as the index - isn't it?

Comment: well the manual saves otherwise. Even if it did, you would need to have about 5 million records at least for there to be a significant saving. Simply not worth it.

Comment: There are a few other things that may be relevant when choosing to use a postgres enum: 1) Sorting text is locale aware, so it's quite a bit slower than sorting ints (as enums are repressented as), this is pervasive as all indexes are sorted according to the locale. 2) If you actually have a specified sorting order for the enum values that is not lexographic it will be hard to achieve

Comment: @edruid such as?

Comment: When you use enums you are typically having only a few rows. So whatever sorting advantage you would have will probably save you about 1 nano second per query. @edruid so that's definitely not worth all this trouble

Comment: I would argue about the usefulness of enums. Surely in OP's use case, a separate `Product` model is better, but there are other use cases as well. F.ex. when only a canonical name is needed (with maybe some ordering information), an enum is way more simple than a separate entity/relation/model. Consider e.g. a `status` attribute, which can only be `CREATED`, `OPEN` & `CLOSED`...

Comment: ... If it's just textual, ordering by their names are not very useful. Surely, when the workflow of such a hypothetical project changes, enum needs DDL statements to adjust that. Which usually requires migrations in the application. But if it were a junction table, which has no UI modification available to it, that application still would require migrations, to insert new rows, remove deprecated ones, etc. I admit, this use case is very slim, but it exists.

Comment: @pozs we are heading into an opiniated discussion but as a rule of thumb enum is evil.

Comment: "ut if it were a junction table, which has no UI modification available to it, that application still would require migrations, to insert new rows, remove deprecated ones," this is not a migration. This is something that the admin can do through the django admin (or a custom admin) a developer or a database admin isn't needed. But you need one or both (maybe all three) if enum was used

Comment: I'm not that familiar with django (and in my example I tried to use an agnostic use case), but if in django, every model can be edited through a UI, then using an enum is actually better. (In my example, it doesn't make sense to just "invent" a new status, let's say `REOPENED`, without backing code changes, which hadles that).

Comment: What about performance time for join statement? if I am using ENUMs I don't need to write any join statement

Comment: join statements do not have any performance impact if you use indexes

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `product` field is incorrect as it specifies that it is array of `CharField`s but it is array of enums in reality. Django [does not](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24342) support enum type now so you can try [this extension](https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields) to define the type correctly:

```
class Product(Enum):
  ProductA = 'a'
  ...

class Campaign(models.Model):
  product = ArrayField(EnumField(Product, max_length=<whatever>))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. see my updated question. thank you so much!

Comment: if I try a single enum it works. but not for ArrayField.

Comment: if I write directly: INSERT INTO campaign ("product") VALUES ('{car,truck}'::product[]) it works just fine

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def django2psql(s):
    return '{'+','.join(s) + '}'

campaign = Campaign(id=5, product=django2psql(["car", "truck"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have to subclass `CharField` to get it to report the correct `db_type`. There may be more problems than this but you can give this a try:

```
class Product(models.CharField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'product'

PRODUCT = (
    ('car', 'car'),
    ('truck', 'truck')
)

class Campaign(models.Model):
    product = ArrayField(Product(null=True, choices=PRODUCT))
```

Comment: I have not actually tested the above, but reading the code it looks as it should work...