# Populating an array of enums

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm having trouble getting enums into my table from my alembic migration.

MVCE here: https://pastebin.com/ng3XcKLf

(SQLAlchemy 1.2, psycopg2 2.7.3.2 and postgres 10.1 - line 15 needs to be modified with your postgres URI)

I read about issues with SQLAlchemy/Postgres and Arrays of Enums, but according to what I could find in issue tracker, that was resolved with 1.1.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Variation 1:** *Attempting to use an attribute of the postgres enum type*

```
op.bulk_insert(permission, [{
    'name': 'ViewContent',
    'contexts': [pgpermissioncontexts.resourceType]
}])
```

This fails with: `AttributeError: 'Enum' object has no attribute 'resourceType'`

**Variation 2:** *attempting to use an attribute of the underlying python Enum*

```
op.bulk_insert(permission, [{
    'name': 'ViewContent',
    'contexts': [PermissionContexts.resourceType]
}])
```

This fails with `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) cols of type permissioncontexts[] but expression is of type text[]`

**Variation 3:** *Casting the string array into an enum array*

```
op.bulk_insert(permission, [{
    'name': 'ViewContent',
    'contexts': sa.cast([PermissionContexts.resourceType], sa.ARRAY(pgenum))
}])
```

This may or may not work - the python process balloons up to using 4GB of memory, and sits there until terminated.

**Variation 4:** *Inserting empty array*

```
op.bulk_insert(permission, [{
    'name': 'ViewContent',
    'contexts': []
}])
```

This works, but, obviously, no value.

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. [this appears to work fine](https://gist.github.com/RazerM/275ab484e33e7832ded42346a5d55e5f)

Comment: Updated with MVCE

Comment: Looking at your gist, I assume this means the problem is something with the alembic bulk_insert () statement. I used this, because I was adding the data as part of an alembic migration, and had the alembic table reference at hand.

I'll see if I can rewrite it to use SqlAlchemy insert()s, and see if that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately arrays of enums don't work out of the box, but there's a [documented workaround](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#using-enum-with-array), 
which is also described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31567612/641234). Using `ArrayOfEnum` instead of `ARRAY`, your variation 2 works:

```
op.bulk_insert(permission, [{
    'name': 'ViewContent',
    'contexts': [PermissionContexts.resourceType],
}])
```

Casting to `ARRAY(permissioncontexts)` should also work, and does work when not using `bulk_insert()`

```
op.execute(permission.insert().values({
    'name': 'ViewContent',
    'contexts': sa.cast([PermissionContexts.resourceType], ARRAY(pgpermissioncontexts)),
}))
```

or when using `bulk_insert(multiinsert=False)`:

```
op.bulk_insert(permission, [{
    'name': 'ViewContent',
    'contexts': sa.cast([PermissionContexts.resourceType], ARRAY(pgpermissioncontexts)),
}], multiinsert=False)
```

There seems to be a bug with either alembic's or sqlalchemy's handling of multiparams.

Comment: I had thought ArrayOfEnums was no longer required after reading this bug thread: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3467/array-of-enums-does-not-allow-assigning

Good to know it's not the case.